# Laravel online status

Tags: php, laravel

I have made custom middleware to track user online status but it has an issue, I can see my own online status but I always see other users as offline while they are not.

#### Code

`Middleware`

```
class UserActivity
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::check()){
            $expiresAt = Carbon::now()->addMinute(1);
            Cache::put('user-is-online-' . Auth::user()->id, true, $expiresAt);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

`Kernel.php`

```
'web' => [
  //...
  \App\Http\Middleware\UserActivity::class,
],
```

`User.php (model)`

```
public function isOnline()
{
  return Cache::has('user-is-online-' . $this->id);
}
```

`views`

```
@if($user->isOnline())
  Online
@else
  Offline
@endif
```

**Any idea why other users status is always not correct?**

`PS:` I'm open to livewire solution if any :)

Comment: `Cache` are stored in users web browser so you r getting for only your online data , in your case use `websocket` presence channel

Comment: @KamleshPaul that make sense, is there any way that we can make it public instead of storing it in user browser beside using websocket? because its running on shared host and running js dependencies is not an option

Comment: use `pusher` for websocket  so you don't need to configure websocket server and create a presence channel so when user vist your website it will join that channel and if left then left the channel by this your can achive

Comment: I dont think the statement about cache being stored in the user browser is right.. It is stored in the server, uses server's filesystem by default.

Comment: @user3532758 that's correct as well, now what do you suggest for my issue?

Comment: Run a code with ajax that updates current time every 2 minutes in database along with user_id and you can simply check if the difference between the updated time and current time is within 120s if yes then user is online else user is offline. I have been using this simple trick in lots of projects and no problem except the latency and little inefficiency. @mafortis

Comment: @stillKonfuzed that's the idea that I had to do it with livewire but I wasn't sure how to execute it, I will try it. Thank you

Comment: If you need some code examples then i can post it as answer here @mafortis

Comment: @stillKonfuzed that would be great.

Comment: I don't see any issue with your code, you **do** navigate with other users, then refreshing the page with your user (in private navigation or an other browser), all that in less than 1 minute, is that right?

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier no that's not fully right see this screenshot https://ibb.co/8Y2PRqj `ps:` this tabs are active about 10 min now

Comment: "that's not fully right " So what do you do? Livewire won't refresh the page automatically. You need to use [polling](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/polling) (reload the component every 2 seconds) or using websocket if you want something instant. Also, if the user don't perform any action in the page, after 1 minute it will be offline.

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier livewire is polling every 2 minute, so the part you said I do all that under 1 min is wrong. + the screenshot I've just sent you is not livewire based, is screenshot of my blade code `@if(...)` which i shared in my question, this code regardless of polling should show users status.

Comment: It's every 2 seconds and you can have even less using this way: `<div wire:poll.750ms>` your question is `Any idea why other users status is always not correct`  But it looks like you're waiting on your active tab to see the status suddenly change to be online when a user is online. But it **cannot** happens without polling or websocket. So I have a legitimate question to ask if the scenario I first asked works in the first place.

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier here is the logic in my mind which this question is based on: i want to see both my users online status (as my screenshot) without any live change of status. For now I can deal with manually refresh the pages it's fine by me, when this is done i will deal with live changes.

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier no idea then?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking then. You **cannot** change the visible online status without live change or refreshing. At some point you need to ask the server "Is he online?" If you want to see the online status getting updated, you **need** either to refresh the page or refresh the div (using polling every X seconds or using websocket). _Note: You don't need livewire to do polling. You can use native javascript_

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier I try my best to simplify it for you: `1` forget about live update `2` I want to use refresh the page `3` forget about livewire `4` forget about javascript **clear so far?** `imagine this logic` user 1 is in page `x` (alone) user 2 comes to page `x` as well, now user 2 should be able to see himself and user 1 `both online` and if user 1 refresh the page now he should as well se both of them online. but this does not happen currently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226971/discussion-between-clement-baconnier-and-mafortis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging in the chat we have resolved the issues;

#### Cache driver issue

Instead of using `CACHE_DRIVER=array` you have to use `CACHE_DRIVER=file`

**Reason** : `array` is used for testing purpose only and the state will not be persisted in cache between requests.

#### Livewire key issue

You have use `<livewire:my-component key="UNIQUE_ID" />` or `<div wire:key="UNIQUE_ID"></div>` when the content is inside a `foreach` or `if` condition and updated by livewire.

Livewire keeps reference of them to update the DOM. Without, Livewire may update the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should to use database? I do so:

In authizied middleware:
`app(WriteUserRepository::class)->updateLastActive();`

In repository:

```
 public function updateLastActive()
{
    $this->model = ReadUserRepository::getCurrentUser();
    $this->model->last_active = now();

    return $this->save();
}
```

UsersOnline scope from User model looks like:

```
 private const timeToOffline = 120; // seconds

public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::addGlobalScope(function ($query) {
        $query->where('last_active', ">", Carbon::now()->subSecond(self::timeToOffline));
    });
}
```

Then you can get all online users and do what you want with it. If your User model is big you can create only specific query from users repository and select only online users Ids without all information.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery :

```
setInterval(()=>{
 $.post('yourUrl.php',{user_id:user_id},(send_online)=>{ console.log(check_online );} );
},200000); //2minutes interval
```

Php :

```
if(isset($_POST['user_id'])){
 $user_id = $_POST['user_id']; $current_time = date('d-m-Y g:i:s');
 $query = $con->prepare("Update users set last_online = ? where user_id = ?");
 $query->execute([$current_time,$user_id ]);
}
```

Checking part (server side php):

```
$getUser = $con->prepare("Select * from users where user_id = ?");
$getUser->exec....and fetch etc then check
if(timeDiff($Users->last_online) < 2){ echo "is_online";} else{ echo "offline"; }
```

Time diff checker function :

```
function timeDiff($last_online){
 $to_time = strtotime(date('d-m-Y g:i:s'));
 $from_time = strtotime($last_online);
 return round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 60,2);
}
```